# pass value from multiple div to ajax on page load and on change

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to re-use the same code on several web pages to tidy up the code, especially when the same AJAX response in used once/few times on the page.
The response is a list of `<option>` to be placed into `<select>`.

On a NEW ENTRY to database page load, I want the `<select>` to be filled with correct `<options>`.

On an UPDATE to database page load, I want the `<select>` to be initially filled with selected `<option selected>`, but when `.change` is triggered, the cascading `<select>` must update accordingly.

Everything worked as expected, until I've decided to reuse the same code (response from Ajax) instead of having separate php syntax inside each `<select>`.

Now, when the page is loading the `<select>` values in all div's gets overwritten by the value from the last one.

Any Idea on how to accomplish this?

here is my code so far:

**webpage.php**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-2"><input type="hidden" class="deptList_value" value="<?php echo $row['fDeptFK'];?>">
        <select class="form-control deptList" name="deptFK" onchange="getId(this.value);" required>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2"><input type="" class="areaList_value" value="<?php echo $row['PK'].'-'.$row['fDeptFK'].'-'.$row['fAreaFK'];?>">
         <select class="form-control areaList" name="areaFK" required>
         </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".deptList_value").each(function() {
    var deptPK = $(this).val();
    //alert(deptPK);
    $.ajax({
           url:"../GetData_DropDown/getdataDeptQA.php",
           method:"POST",
           data:{DeptNo:deptPK},
           dataType:"text",
           success:function(data)
           {
                $('.deptList').html(data);
           }
    });
});

$(".areaList_value").each(function() {
    var arr = $(this).val().split('-');
    var idPK = arr[0];
    var deptPK = arr[1];
    var areaPK =arr[2];

    $.ajax({
            url:"../GetData_DropDown/getdataAreaQA.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{AreaNo:areaPK,DeptNo:deptPK},
            dataType:"text",
            success:function(data)
            {
                 $('.areaList').html(data);
            }
    });
});

$('.deptList').change(function(){
    var deptPK = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
            url:"../GetData_DropDown/getdataAreaQA.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{DeptNo:deptPK},
            dataType:"text",
            success:function(data)
            {
                 $('.areaList').html(data);
            }
    });
});
```

**getdataAreaQA.php**

```
$output = '<option value=""></option>';
foreach($conn->query("EXEC [qa].[getQA_area_list] ".$_POST["DeptNo"]) as $rowA) {
    if ($rowA['PK']==$_POST['AreaNo']) {
        $output .= '<option value="'.$rowA['PK'].'" data-AP24FKvalue="'.$rowA['AP24FK'].'" selected>'.$rowA['Name'].'</option>';
    } else {
        $output .= '<option value="'.$rowA['PK'].'" data-AP24FKvalue="'.$rowA['AP24FK'].'">'.$rowA['Name'].'</option>';
    }
}

echo $output;
```

EDIT 
Not tested but this should work on a page with single row from database. The issue is with paginated pages with multiple rows on one page.

Comment: What it sounds like though... is you have multiple selects with the same class, say `areaList` ... so yeah, the ajax return is targetting all of those to return its html options into. You may need to enumerate your selects, or add data-attr to target specific ones based on the same values you pull from the hidden input that initiates the ajax call.

Comment: @incredibleHat, Yes that's my intention to somehow differentiate between all instances of the same class... I've tried to do it with this line:`var arr = $(this).val().split('-');` but didn't really worked as intended, I got lost... Can you propose a solution? Regarding the `hidden input`, would this be the best approach?

Comment: It can get complicated pretty fast, trying to adjust what you have into an answer. I may end up rewriting a lot of the logic behind it. Q: Are `$row['PK']` `$row['fDeptFK']` `$row['fAreaFK']` all of those ID's, or clean-strings? If they are string keys or IDs, it will make things easier.

Comment: Yes they all are ID, type INT, I tried to use all 3, as `$row['fDeptFK'] $row['fAreaFK']` can be repeatable, so I've added `$row['PK']` as well

Comment: What about this: `<select class="form-control deptList" name="deptFK" data-UseThisID="<?php echo $row['PK'].'-'.$row['fDeptFK'].'-'.$row['fAreaFK'];?>"> required>
        </select>` instead of hidden input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose you simplify a little bit more, and use specialized unique `id` in combination with your `class` handlers.

Lets first start by adjusting rows output from your loop:

```
<?php 
$idx = 0;
/* your foreach/for/while loop */ {
    $idx++;// just ensuring a unique value to utilize
?>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <select id="dept_<?php echo $idx;?>" 
                data-dept="<?php echo $row['fDeptFK'];?>" 
                data-idx="<?php echo $idx;?>" 
                class="form-control deptList" name="deptFK" required>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
         <select id="area_<?php echo $idx;?>" 
                 data-dept="<?php echo $row['fDeptFK'];?>" 
                 data-area="<?php echo $row['fAreaFK'];?>" 
                 data-idx="<?php echo $idx;?>" 
                 class="form-control areaList" name="areaFK" required>
         </select>
    </div>
</div>
<?php }?>
```

No need for hidden inputs. The data-vars will contain all that you need. Note that each `id` should be unique per row output.

Now some slight adjustments to the jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".deptList").each(function() {
        var idx   = $(this).data('idx');// the unique row id
        var dept  = $(this).data('dept');
        $.ajax({
               url:"../GetData_DropDown/getdataDeptQA.php",
               method:"POST",
               data:{DeptNo: dept},
               dataType:"html",
               success:function(data)
               {
                    $("#dept_"+idx).html(data);// targets unique id
               }
        });
    });

    $(".areaList").each(function() {
        var idx   = $(this).data('idx');
        var dept  = $(this).data('dept');
        var area  = $(this).data('area');
        $.ajax({
                url:"../GetData_DropDown/getdataAreaQA.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:{AreaNo: area, DeptNo: dept},
                dataType:"html",
                success:function(data)
                {
                     $("#area_"+idx).html(data);
                }
        });
    });

    $('.deptList').change(function(){
        var idx   = $(this).data('idx');
        var dept  = $(this).val();// using .val not .data
        $.ajax({
                url:"../GetData_DropDown/getdataAreaQA.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:{DeptNo: dept},
                dataType:"html",
                success:function(data)
                {
                     $("#area_"+idx).html(data);// targets area select
                     // you may want to update the area selects data too:
                     $("#area_"+idx).data('dept', dept);
                }
        });
    });

});
```

By targeting using the row `idx` value, you can ensure which sub select options will be changed out. All the data-vars contain values for what you need to initially populate the `select` options.

**Important Note**

As we discovered through comments... if you try to use capitals in a data-varNAME, it will result in undefined when accessing it with the `.data()` jquery method. So instead, make sure the naming of the data-varname has no caps and it will be ok.

Comment: Thank you. I've copy / pasted and only deptFK lists all options, but none selected, deptList on change doesnt work and areaList doens't work for either load/change :(

Comment: i've opened chrome develoer view and get 500 internal server error... so values dont get passed to getdataAreaQA.php

Comment: This is my example I setup using some dummy data: http://bytejunkies.com/test/4255.php The jquery is the same (this has no db pulls, just sample data). Changing either dept should reset the area list. For simplicity this example uses the same area list for every dept.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue.... those CAP "FK" with the .data method. I've personally never used CAPS in varnames in js, so I never ran across it. But eliminating those will fix the undefined. I'm sorry for initially suggesting using "data-deptFK" since that clearly does not work in jquery with the .data method. I also cleaned up my comment spew ;)

Comment: yes I just found this.... works almost like expected! many thanks! The only issue is now when I change the deptList the area list clears but areaList doesnt update depending on new selection of deptList, it stays the same as per prevous dept

Comment: Hm. So when you change a deptList, you have specific areas per dept, right? I suspect then `getdataAreaQA.php` uses that DeptNo to pull a filtered list and make options from it? And its not doing that? Each time a deptList is changed, it should blow out all options with a whole new build. If I'm understanding you correctly. `var dept  = $(this).val();` ? right ?

Comment: Yes exactly, thanks that fixed it! Everything works like a dream. Many thanks for providing solution and fixing it for me!